# Reordering TableViewCells location doesnt persist

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

Im reordering my TableViewCells with the following code:

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
[self.ammoTable moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableArray count] - 1 inSection:1]];
}

-(IBAction)setEdit{
if ([self.button.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Edit"]) {
    self.ammoTable.editing = YES;
    [self.button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else{
    self.ammoTable.editing = NO;
    [self.button setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   
*)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    // fetch the object at the row being moved
NSString *r = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    // remove the original from the data structure
[self.tableArray removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

    // insert the object at the target row
[self.tableArray insertObject:r atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

[self.ammoTable reloadData];
}
```

Everything works great, except when you leave the view and return to it. If i move the cells around, when the view comes back up, they are all in the original order that they were in. Is there any reason for this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are reloading your tableview with old array i.e. not with updated array
that means you are reinitializing your array ,it may be in viewDidLoad.
create & initialize your array in appDelegate .Use this array & make changes when you moves cell,it will persist order of elements.

see this link to [how to create & access array from appDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756120/how-to-copy-an-array-to-appdelegate-array-and-then-retrieve-it-again-elsewhere)

Comment: where should i initialize the array? Inside of `didFinishLaunching`

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are loading data from some sort of array.  In addition to moving the cells in the table, you must also do the same to this array.

Comment: Why is it that when i don't reorder the cells, the array automatically remembers the order? But if i want to reorder i must manually make it remember the state?

Comment: When the table view requests a cell using the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you probably are retrieving information from your array and creating a cell.  In this case, you are receiving information in the incorrect order since the array was not properly arranged to match the ordering of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the changes you make to the `tableArray` property so when you reload that array again the next time the view is displayed, the rows are loaded in the new order.

Comment: Okay, if im using core data in my app, couldnt i just somehow add the array to my model and store the info that way?

Comment: I haven't used Core Data but you should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. As you reorder the rows, you should update something in the entity so next time it will be retrieved in the proper order.

Comment: Do you know if it is very difficult to transfer to a `NSFetchedResultsController` once the whole app is done in just core data?

Comment: As I said, I've never used Core Data. My limited understanding is that `NSFetchedResultsController` makes showing data from Core Data in a table view much easier but I have no idea what it takes to redo your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes in the tableview cells you also need to make same changes in the tablearray. otherwise tableview cells get loaded as per order in the array.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex

> Why is it that when i don't reorder the cells, the array automatically
>   remembers the order? But if i want to reorder i must manually make it
>   remember the state?

You see Alex, the array doesn't remember any order, it is the table that arranges itself according to the array. That is the whole point of the data source. Manipulate the data source and you can manipulate the table. But manipulating the table doesn't alter the datasource. So if you are making some changes to your table, remember to change the dataSource beforehand to reflect the same.

> For eg. say you want to delete a row from the table. If you go to
>   **commitEditing** method and simply delete the row, you will end up
>   crashing, with an invalid update or inconsistency exception. You need
>   to first delete the data for the corresponding cell from the
>   dataSource, then delete the row.

Same in your case ..first interchange the objects in your data Array, then move the rows accordingly.

Hope I am clear. Cheers and have fun.